# Rearrange text file based on matches in columns

Tags: python, unix, awk

I am working with a data set:

```
ALI P 18:00:40.583 0.0

ALI S 18:00:58.188 1.4

BRD Pg 18:00:48.918 0.4

BRD Sg 18:01:09.437 -1.8

GAN Pn 18:00:58.207 -0.0

GAN Sn 18:01:27.791 0.1

GLB P 18:00:27.265 -0.4

GLB S 18:00:34.187 0.1

GOB S 18:01:13.638 -0.6

IML Pg 18:00:52.264 -0.6
```

Using AWK and I need lines that match, to be printed onto the same line.

i.e.

```
ALI P 18:00:40.583 0.0 ALI S 18:00:58.188 1.4

BRD Pg 18:00:48.918 0.4 BRD Sg 18:01:09.437 -1.8
```

I've been trying all sorts of different ideas but cannot locate code to do this.
I have been trying to use AWK, as instructed by my superior. Would be interested to see if it would be easier in Python?

(note white space between lines to preserve structure)

Comment: not clear what you are matching on. Would `grep 'Event|ALI|BRD' file` give you the matching (and output) you need? Good luck.

Comment: I'm matching on the three letter combination in column 1. I'm extremely new to coding. Basically, if two consecutive lines match, (like the first two) I'd like to print them onto the same line.

Comment: Explain why the the GAN, GLB, GOB, and IML lines aren't present in the output. No, whatever text manipulation you are trying to do it would not be easier in python.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you are matching on the first field and the file is sorted.  In that case, try:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{printf "%s%s",($1==last?" ":"\n"),$0}; NR==1{printf "%s",$0} {last=$1} END{print""}' file
ALI P 18:00:40.583 0.0 ALI S 18:00:58.188 1.4
BRD Pg 18:00:48.918 0.4 BRD Sg 18:01:09.437 -1.8
GAN Pn 18:00:58.207 -0.0 GAN Sn 18:01:27.791 0.1
GLB P 18:00:27.265 -0.4 GLB S 18:00:34.187 0.1
GOB S 18:01:13.638 -0.6
IML Pg 18:00:52.264 -0.6
```

#### How it works

- `NR==1{printf "%s",$0}`

  For the first line, we print it with no trailing newline.
- `NR>1{printf "%s%s",($1==last?" ":"\n"),$0}`

  For lines after the first, we print a space if the first fields match or a newline if they don't, followed by the line.

  The tricky-looking part here is the ternary statement `$1==last?" ":"\n"`.  This just tests to see if the first field is equal to the last first field.  If it is, it returns the string after the `?`.  If it isn't, it returns the string after the `:`.
- `last=$1`

  We update the variable `last` to the most recent first field.
- `END{print""}`

  After we have finished reading the file and to make sure that we have a complete final line, we print a newline.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Can you explain what the code is doing and maybe how exactly you thought of it?

Comment: @noconceptoflunch See updated answer for an explanation.  _"how exactly you thought of it?"_  Experience helps.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] FS $0:$0} 
    END{for(k in a) print a[k] | "sort" }' file | column -t

ALI  P   18:00:40.583  0.0   ALI  S   18:00:58.188  1.4
BRD  Pg  18:00:48.918  0.4   BRD  Sg  18:01:09.437  -1.8
GAN  Pn  18:00:58.207  -0.0  GAN  Sn  18:01:27.791  0.1
GLB  P   18:00:27.265  -0.4  GLB  S   18:00:34.187  0.1
GOB  S   18:01:13.638  -0.6
IML  Pg  18:00:52.264  -0.6
```

accumulate records with the same key, print at the end and sort (by the key), `column` for prettying.  Doesn't require the keys to be contiguous or sorted.

Answer (score 1):

This could be approached in Python as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = """ALI P 18:00:40.583 0.0
ALI S 18:00:58.188 1.4
BRD Pg 18:00:48.918 0.4
BRD Sg 18:01:09.437 -1.8
GAN Pn 18:00:58.207 -0.0
GAN Sn 18:01:27.791 0.1
GLB P 18:00:27.265 -0.4
GLB S 18:00:34.187 0.1
GOB S 18:01:13.638 -0.6
IML Pg 18:00:52.264 -0.6"""    

print '\n'.join(' '.join(g) for k,g in groupby(data.splitlines(), key=lambda x: x.split()[0]))
```

This would display:

```
ALI P 18:00:40.583 0.0 ALI S 18:00:58.188 1.4
BRD Pg 18:00:48.918 0.4 BRD Sg 18:01:09.437 -1.8
GAN Pn 18:00:58.207 -0.0 GAN Sn 18:01:27.791 0.1
GLB P 18:00:27.265 -0.4 GLB S 18:00:34.187 0.1
GOB S 18:01:13.638 -0.6
IML Pg 18:00:52.264 -0.6
```